# Checking convex polygon intersection in less than O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, complexity-theory, computational-geometry

I have 2 convex polygons (2d) and I would like to check if the 2 polygons intersect. In fact, I will move and rotate the polygons many times, so I can also do some precomputations to obtain a fast answer to this problem.

I am looking for a low complexity algorithm.

I know that it is possible to check that a point lie in a convex polygon in O(log(n)), and I was wondering if I can do some kind of dichotomy around the points of the other polygon to obtain the result. If there any existing algorithms / papers on this topic ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible in O(log(n)): https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~chazelle/pubs/IntersectConvexObjects2-3Dim.pdf

Comment: What are the typical values of n ? A first approach is by a tight bounding circle. Axis-parallel bounding box (then rotated) is another option.

Comment: n can be something about 500 points. Yes, i will do some first tests to exclude fast.

Answer (score 4):

The [Gilbert–Johnson–Keerthi(GJK) algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Keerthi_distance_algorithm) is just what you are looking for. It is surprisingly easy to implement and it detects collision in O(log(n)).

Comment: Are you sure about the Log(n) bound ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I can not find a reference on the complexity online, but this is the bound I studied in university several years ago.

Comment: The original paper says "Extensive numerical experience with a broad family of polytopes in R3 shows that the computational cost is approximately linear in the total number of vertices specifying the two polytopes."

Comment: Finding the extremal in one direction is Log(n) in R2, but perhaps it is harder in R3.

Comment: @Renaud: can GJK for 2D exploit that ?

Comment: I have been using hill climbing for this, but this is not specific for 2D, same approach can be used for 3D. I think there are two options - we studied an optimized version that has better complexity, or I am wrong and the complexity is linear. I am trying to find more information.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: can you guarantee O(Log(n)) with hill climbing ? I doubt it.

Comment: You can guarantee finding the extremal with hill climbing in O(log(n)) just like you can with ternary search.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: how do you achieve that ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust here is a [paper](https://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs468-01-fall/Papers/cameron.pdf) that considers the hill climbing optimization

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: this hill climbing procedure has all appearances of being worst-case linear, as it moves one edge at a time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103125/discussion-between-ivaylo-strandjev-and-yves-daoust).

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes of course in 2d, the function "Support" can be in Log(n) however, it is hard to know/bound how many times this function must be call.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Is this (support in Log(n)) still true in 3d/higher dimension ?

Comment: @renaud: why do you ask me ? I don't believe that GJK is Log(n). Polygon intersection detection can indeed by solved in O(Log(n)), as established by Chazelle, but the solution isn't simple.